# CameraX ImageView wont display taken image

Tags: android, camera, imageview, android-imageview, android-camerax

I've got two Fragments:

**Fragment CameraXPicture**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#FF000000"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.CameraImp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/preview_area"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no">


    </androidx.camera.view.PreviewView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/captureImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**PictureCropp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.FragmentCroppImage">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    //hardcoded for testing reasons
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/takenPicture"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My CameraXPicture Fragment takes a picture and passes the picture forward to the FragmentImageCropp:

```
private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        imageCapture.takePicture(executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
            @Override
            public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {

                FragmentCroppImage fragment2 = new FragmentCroppImage();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putByteArray("takenPic", imageProxyToBitmapByteArray(image));// length returns 6489014
                fragment2.setArguments(args);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLHaupt, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
});



private byte[] imageProxyToBitmapByteArray(ImageProxy image) {
    ImageProxy.PlaneProxy planeProxy = image.getPlanes()[0];
    ByteBuffer buffer = planeProxy.getBuffer();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    return bytes;
}
```

My FragmentImageCropp has only the job to display the image:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        bitmapAsArray = getArguments().getByteArray("takenPic");

        Log.e("received length",""+bitmapAsArray.length); //receives 6489014
    }
}

ImageView takenPicture;
byte[] bitmapAsArray = new byte[3]; //testvalue
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    takenPicture = view.findViewById(R.id.takenPicture);
    takenPicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapAsArray, 0, bitmapAsArray.length));
}
```

The issue is that the ImageView wont display the image. The ImageView remains "emtpy".

The issue is that I don't know what the issue might be. Is it cause the image get wrong converted to a bytearray or is it due the convertion of the bytearray to a bitmap?

The reason I am using a bytearray is that transferring a object(proxyimage) would take much longer, and I want to prevent long delays as much as possible.

**EDIT**
It seems that the convertion itself is not the issue right know. I tried displaying a picture hardcoded it does not get displayed

Comment: were you able to find any solution for the issue ? @Savan

Comment: @oyeraghib it was a long time I ago but I fixed the issue. Altough I can't remember what the solution was exactly. Are u stuck with the same problem? I can send u my code including the layout files if u watn

Comment: yes please send, that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @oyeraghib how would u want me to send it to you? is pastebin ok for you?

Comment: can you send it like a GitHub gist? Or upload it as a repo on GitHub ?

Comment: It would take too long, I'll put the code as pastebin.

Comment: Picture Capture Fragment: https://pastebin.com/J3WSHsyy including layout https://pastebin.com/UZQKuNun

Comment: Picture Accept Fragment: https://pastebin.com/KTjPd0b9 icluding layout: https://pastebin.com/k5QZm3b2

Comment: @SavanLuffy Any idea how can I capture the image with set real-time filter using Camerax android?

Answer (score 0):

onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
Uri selectedImageUri = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapUtils.loadFromUri(MainActivity.this, selectedImageUri);

```
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

}
oncapture success there is an overide method onimage saved from that you can set the image to your imageview